# Object is not being produced on calling [Symbol.iterator]()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, iterable

This is this source code:

```
const james = {
    name: 'James',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185,
    [Symbol.iterator]:function*(){
    yield Object.keys(this) ;   
    }
};
const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();
//
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 'James'
console.log(iterator.next().value); // `5'10`
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 185
```

The first call to `iterator.next().value` is supposed to print

```
{"value":"James","key":"name","done":false}
```

but it is printing `{"value":["name","height","weight"],"done":false}`. How to resolve this?

Comment: Where would a `key` in an iteration result come from? `Object.keys` produces the array `["name","height","weight"]` and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `yield` all keys at once. Means that your first `next` do all work. All you need is to iterate over the keys and `yield` them in sequence.

```js
const james = {
    name: 'James',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185,
    [Symbol.iterator]:function*(){   
       for(let key of Object.keys(this)) {
          yield  { propValue: this[key], propName: key};       
       }       
    }
};

const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
```

Comment: It is printing the value and done. It should also print the key part.

Comment: The syntax of the generator return value is `{ value, done }`. You can at the value has an object with the property value and name. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this would be the solution you are looking for, it outputs exactly what you need it to output.

```
const james = {
  name: 'James',
  height: `5'10"`,
  weight: 185,
  [Symbol.iterator]: function() {
    let keys = Object.keys(this), index = 0;
    return {
      next: () => { 
        return {
          key: keys[index], value: this[keys[index]], done: ++index >= keys.length 
        };  
      }
    }
  }
}

const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
```