# Method to produce key, value and done in the format {value: .. , key: .. , done: ..}

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

.next() method returns an object with two properties i.e. value and done. Is there a method that returns key along with the value and done? Here's the code:

```
const james = {
    name: 'James',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185,
    [Symbol.iterator]:function*(){   
       for(let key of Object.keys(this)) {
          yield  this[key]; 
       }
    }
};

const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next()); 
console.log(iterator.next()); 
console.log(iterator.next());
```

The output of this code is:

```
{ value: 'James', done: false }
{ value: '5\'10"', done: false }
{ value: 185, done: false }
```

Expected output:

```
{ value: 'James', key: 'name', done: false }
{ value: '5\'10"', key: 'height', done: false }
{ value: 185, key: 'weight', done: false }
```

Comment: For generator functions? No. They just emit a value and done. What key are you wanting to return? Can you not `yield` all the data you want as a single object?

Comment: The key in the key:value pair of object properties

Comment: What object? Please show us the whole use case. Are you using generators like i guessed?

Comment: Okay.. I'll update it..

Comment: I updated the code..

Comment: [As we explained before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47725541/1048572), no there is not. That's not how iterators/generators work. Why would you need that, what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?? The usual behaviour for `entries` iterators is to have a tuple (two-element array) as the yielded value.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will get in a generator will be to yield the object yourself

```
yield {key: key, value: this[key]};
```

```js
const james = {
  name: 'James',
  height: `5'10"`,
  weight: 185,
  [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
    for (let key of Object.keys(this)) {
      yield {
        key: key,
        value: this[key]
      };
    }
  }
};

const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own iteration wrapper function, like this:

```js
const james = {
    name: 'James',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185,
};

// Custom iterator wrapper
const iterate = (obj) => {
  function* iter(){   
       for(let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
          yield {key: key, value: obj[key]}; 
       }
  }
  return () => {
    const r = iter().next();
    return {key: r.value.key, value: r.value.value, done: r.done};
  }
}


const next = iterate(james);

console.log( next() ); 
console.log( next() ); 
console.log( next() );
```